# Strict Standards: Non-static method

Tags: php, methods, static, strict

I'm running Ubuntu + PHP 5.4 and got such error:

> Strict Standards: Non-static method XTemplate::I() should not be
>   called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   ...
>   on line 339

And that method looks like this:

```
interface ITemplate
{
    public function I();
}

class XTemplate implements ITemplate
{
    public function I()
    {
             ...
    }
}
```

And this code is running normal on Windows 7 in XAMPP.
I have found only advices to turn off error_reporing, but I need to solve it.
Do I need to install some modules on turn on some other settings in php.ini ?

Comment: How do you call the function I()?

Comment: I call it like that: XTemplate::I()->makeTemplate(...);

Answer (score 4):

You are getting the error message because you are calling the function statically instead of creating an instance of XTemplate class. Depending on your situation, either make the function static:

```
static public function I()
    {
             ...
    }
```

Or first create an instance of XTemplate:

```
$myXtemplate = new XTemplate();
$myXtemplate->I();
```

I hope this answers your question.

Edit:
[This page](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2010/declaring-static-methods-in-php) may be interesting to you.

Answer (score -1):

I had same error, all you need is a change in Interface:
     `public function I();` change to
     `public static function I();` and when you create instance use

```
public static function I();
```

I hope this help.