# Strict Standards: Non-static method Error in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, components, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I developed one Joomla Component. In Administrator Part I display Dynamic Category using `helper/select.php` file. But I got this error:

> Strict Standards: Non-static method `TrueMatrimonyHelperSelect::getProfileforlist()` should not be called statically, assuming `$this` from incompatible context

### XML Code:

```html
<field name="createby" type="list" id="createby"                     
    source_file="admin://components/com_astrimony/helpers/select.php"
    source_class="TrueMatrimonyHelperSelect" source_method="getProfileforlist"
    sortable="true" tdwidth="15%" show_link="true" url="index.php?option=astrimony&amp;view=profile&amp;id=[ITEM:ID]"
    label="COM_MATRIMONY_REGISTER_FOR" 
/>
```

### Select File Code

```php
public function getProfileforlist($name='', $attr=array(), $selected_value='', $id='') {                
        $items = FOFModel::getTmpInstance('Profilerefers', 'TrueMatrimonyModel')->enabled(1)->getList(true);        
        $result = array();      
        $result[] = JHtml::_('select.option','',JText::_('COM_TRUEMATRIMONY_SELECT_PROFILE_FOR'));
        foreach($items as $item) {
            $result[$item->profilerefer_id] = $item->profile_reference;
        }   //print_r($result);exit;        
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Non-static method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897797/strict-standards-non-static-method)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `public function getProfileforlist` to `public static function getProfileforlist`